# Word VBA Runtime Error 5460 on second Documents.Add in global template

Tags: vba, office365, ms-word

For a customer, I have created a Global template with a ’New Document” button that shows a userform letting the user create a new document from a choice of templates, e.g. Letter, Invoice, etc.
Recently, we have added the choice Report.

The code executed from this userform is very simple, using e.g.

```
Documents.Add Template:="Letter.dotm", NewTemplate:=False
```

to create the new documents.

The Report template is – by my standards – quite complex, with AutoNew and AutoClose macros, an EventClassModule, it writes to and reads from the CustomDocumentProperties, opens several specific Word documents from where it copies text and pastes it into the Report document, etc.

The first time a new Report is created it works as planned; but the second time (in the same Word session) the Report option is used, a ‘Runtime Error 5460’ occurs. And after that, any of the other document options returns the same error.

Quitting Word and starting a new Word session sets everything back to normal, until the Report template again is called the second time.

Strangely enough, the Report template works with no errors when new documents based on it are created directly from Explorer, as many times in the same Word session as needed.

The problem occurs in Word 2016 (365) with Windows 7 Pro, but not in Word 2013 with Windows 10.

Anybody that has ever experienced anything like this??  Help is really appreciated.

---

Runtime Error 5460: 'A file error has occured.'

Debug is not possible.

The Report template has thousands of lines of code and I have not been able to find out if it is in fact code in the Report template that causes the error, or code in the Global template.

As said, the Report template works fine when used from Explorer, and when called via the Global template in 2013 everything works there too.

---

Problem solved! 
I followed the advice from @macropod and added the path also.
In stead of just using

```
'…
If OptionButton3.Value = True Then
    Documents.Add Template:="Report.dot", NewTemplate:=False
End If
'…
```

I changed the code to:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim strPath As String
strPath = Options.DefaultFilePath(wdWorkgroupTemplatesPath)

Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

'…
If OptionButton3.Value = True Then
    wdApp.Documents.Add Template:=strPath & "\Report.dot", NewTemplate:=False
End If
'…

End Sub
```

Thanks!!

Comment: where's the VBA code? Add it. Most likely, by your problem statement, you are using   `documents.add` on an open instance of the word. This operation  not supported anymore.

Comment: We really need to see the code that triggers the error. Also the MESSAGE of the error would help - no one memorizes error numbers. My inclination is that it could have something to do with "opens several specific Word documents from where it copies text and pastes". Better might be to either bookmark these passages and use InsertFile with the Bookmark parameter OR save these passages as BuildingBlocks in the template.

Comment: Try supplying the path for the template as well...

Comment: Problem solved!  Thanks @macropod